# Combining and/ or operator in JS (jQuery) with if/else statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I am having issues in combining `&&` and `||` operators together in a jQuery if/else statement. Here is an example

```
if(($x == 'on') && ($y !== 'on' || $z !== 'on')){

// it does not seem to work

}
```

However, if I place only one of them, it works. Example

```
if($x == 'on' && $y !== 'on' ){

// it works but I want to combine more like the above 
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the requirement? I suggest you to spend some time on basics

Comment: The first one. I need to check if one variable is true and either of a set of variable is not true. Eg. $x must be true and either $y OR $z OR $anyThing is not true

Comment: `if(($x === 'on') && !($y === 'on' || $z === 'on')){` This may not be correct but this is more along the lines of how i'd do it.
need more details regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement and as per the comments "$x must be true and either $y OR $z OR $anyThing is not true". You may have  to add additional lines of code.

Please refer below code and test it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){       
        $('#testBtn').on('click', function(){           
            var xInput = $('#xInput').val(),
            yInput = $('#yInput').val(),
            zInput = $('#zInput').val();

            if(xInput == 'true' && (yInput == 'false' && zInput == 'false')){               
                $('#result').text("X it 'true'; Y & Z are 'false'");
            } else if(yInput == 'true' && (zInput == 'false' && xInput == 'false')){                
                $('#result').text("Y it 'true'; X & Z are 'false'");
            } else if(zInput == 'true' && (yInput == 'false' && xInput == 'false')){                
                $('#result').text("Z it 'true'; X & Y are 'false'");
            } else {
                $('#result').text("Try Again...");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
       X: <input type="text" id="xInput"> &nbsp 
       Y: <input type="text" id="yInput"> &nbsp 
       Z: <input type="text" id="zInput"> &nbsp  
       <br/>
       <br/>
       <button id="testBtn">Test If Condition</button>
       <br/>
       <br/>
       Result: <span id="result"></span>
</body>
</html>
```